# Serving up unique content (not translations) based on user location within one shared site structure. (PHP/MySQL )

Tags: php, mysql, localization, internationalization

**Some Context:**
We currently have 5 versions of our site (US, UK, CA, AU, SG) with TLDs for each.  We have just decided to expand this to 10-12 sites that will representing 4 or 5 languages (our current sites are only in English).

We will use the TLD for each country  (i.e. www.domain.fr) as well as our “.com” with country and language in the path (i.e. www.domain.com/fr/fr) all pointing to the same site/files and hopefully even using the same CSS file(s).

I think we have resolved how to serve up different text content based on the users locale (zend_translate or, possibly, GetText).   However, some of the locations will also need to host unique images or other location-specific content within the established structure (Say, hypothetically, that there are 3 blocks/divs in which we place different “ads” based on users location).

**Question:**
Is there a PHP/MySQL specific “best way” to serve up some unique content based on user’s location -- all within a single shared site structure? (Please note this is not about translation, but about location specific content)

**Example:**
A really great example of what we would like to achieve is ikea.com, ikea.pl, ikea.com/pl/pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hypothetically there isn't a `PHP`/`MySQL` specific **best way**.

The best way, there is, is the way to think it, it all depends on what you need. For your small **ads** problem, if you are not using any HUGE ADS companies that can target client location, you can use `MySQL` and create `block` specific zones for each `TLD`, so you can run different content in every domain in that block of data.

Images can be hosted in same place, same directory if they have unique names, and again you can use MySQL to keep track what you have and where.

eg:

```
$myTLD = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; // get host
$myTLD = preg_replace('#^www\.(.+\.)#i', '$1', $myTLD); // remove www if exists
switch ($myTLD) {
    case 'example.org':
        include 'banners_for_org.php';
        break;
    case 'example.net':
        include 'banners_for_net.php';
        break;
    default:
        include 'banners_general.php';
}
```

(PS: I don't see anything similar from `ikea.pl` in `ikea.com`, not even the logo)

Comment: Thanks Mihai.  So I can use block specific zones for each TLD within the same site.  This was what I was asking about, but am curious **how**, can you point me in the right direction.  I don't mind researching and trial and error, I am just hoping to get my efforts going in the right direction.

The ads were just a hypothetical, we will actually create our own content in those blocks.

Lastly, sorry about IKEA, I am simply forwarded from ikea.pl to ikea.com/pl/pl so I did not realize they are different.

Comment: Based on the domain you are in, with `$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']`, I will paste a small code

Comment: This helps a lot.  Thanks Mihai!